# function is not defined error when moved function names to external config file/module

Tags: javascript, node.js

so i had my setting/config code in the main script like

```
lobal_banks = {

    1 : {func_ : function(s){ bank_1(s)} ,  url : 'https://example.com'   , 'password' : '456'  } ,
    2 : {func_ : function(s){ bank_1(s)} ,  url : 'https://example2.com'  , 'password' : '123'   } ,
};
```

and i used them like

```
global_banks[1].func_( setting );
```

to call their function and worked , then i decided to move the config files to a seperate file so i created a file `config.js`

```
var config = {};

config.banks = {

    1 : {func_ : function(s){ bank_1(s)} ,  url : 'https://example.com'   , 'password' : '456'  } ,
    2 : {func_ : function(s){ bank_1(s)} ,  url : 'https://example2.com'  , 'password' : '123'   } ,
};


module.exports = config;
```

and i changed the main script to

```
var config = require('./config');
 config.banks[setting.bank_id].func_( setting );
```

now i get

```
ReferenceError: bank_1 is not defined
```

what is wrong ? `bank_1` function is the main script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `bank_1(s)` function is not defined in config.js -- you need to do something like

```
var config = {};

var bank_1 = function(s){
  console.log(s);
}

config.banks = {

    1 : {func_ : function(s){ bank_1(s)} ,  url : 'https://example.com'   , 'password' : '456'  } ,
    2 : {func_ : function(s){ bank_1(s)} ,  url : 'https://example2.com'  , 'password' : '123'   } ,
};


module.exports = config;
```